# Default Icon on iPad - for an iPhone app

Tags: ios, xcode, xcasset

When I launch my iPhone app on the iPad its' icon stays the default iOS icon. 
In my AppIcon in `AssetCatalog.xcassets` I added icons for iOS 7-11 (76pt 1x and 2x). Still no change.

Note the app is an iPhone app and not universal.

Any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: Have you tried to delete the app from your iPad before build it?

Comment: Yes I have. No change.

Comment: Did you check the build log for additional warning message?

Comment: There's no warning in the debug console.

Comment: If you open you xcassets and check the attribute inspector, is iPad selected or did you only add iPhone icons. If you have both selected check if the image sizes you added are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `info.plist` make sure you **don't have** the following keys.

```
<key>CFBundleIcons</key>
<dict/>
<key>CFBundleIcons~ipad</key>
<dict/>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**While adding assets to Assets.xcassets update the property for asset using inspector window.**

**1. Select iPhone if you want that asset should available for iPhone only.**

[image]